# Differentiating between Two Orthographic Projections

Tags: technical-drawing, machine-design

I came across the infamous control handle assembly in two different books, referencing the views differently. One of the had it like the following photo[image: One of the two labeling of the two views of the control handle body]

The other book labelled the side view in this photo as the elevation (front view).
The question here is how to determine the correct choice of views? I remember from school that this will also determine the dimensioning on the views (in which direction numbers are put, and their relative positions' to the dimension lines), so if somebody could point me to the standard used in settling this issue.

One colleague told me the elevation should be the view with the greatest dimension, but I think the given example doesn't totally agree with this point. I mean there should be a decisive factor because in many machine parts it is not obvious which is which.

Comment: In my opinion, it depends whether when it is used (either during operation or assembly) which way around it is. If the lever is pulled towards the operator, the image is correct. If it’s tilted left/right as you look at it, then the described alternative would be better.

Comment: IMO this sort of question is mostly relevant to books that *teach* technical drawing, which tend to "set puzzles" to make the student understand exactly what is being drawn. In the real world views are often drawn wherever they will fit on the page, are *labeled* to show how they relate to each other, and are often not at right angles to each other anyway. "Plan, (front) elevation and side view" tend to be used in civil engineering where it is obvious which way up a building or a bridge is supposed to be, but for a small mechanical part like this they don't really mean anything.

Comment: we used to call what you have as elevation, a section.

Comment: @kamran Indeed, it is a sectioned elevation. But it is an elevation nonetheless.

Comment: @M.Abelshafy A section cuts through a part, an elevation is taken from outside the part looking at it is what I am used to to distinguish those two terms.